# How to handle Inter State DAG exeution

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Both DAG A and DAG B run at the same time. for example 10 AM. DAG A complete in 5 minutes and DAG B will wait for the execution state of DAG A if the state is successful then DAG B will move to the next step otherwise will throw the error. DAB B always takes the execution state of DAG A on the same day and time. For example - Suppose DAG A ran yesterday successfully but today it is not started due to some issue but DAG B started and should not consider the previous run state. DAG B should consider DAG A's current execution state.
If the execution state is other than failed, success then how to handle the code.

I am new to Airflow and don't know how to handle this

**Code**

```
def status(**context):
        try:
            TI = context["task_instance"]
            exuection_date = context["execution_date"]
            run_state_intra = []
            run_id_intra = []
            
            for data_tuple in (
                settings.Session()
                .query(DR.dag_id, DR.execution_date, DR.state, DR.run_id)
                .order_by(DR.execution_date.desc())
                .limit(1)
            ):
```

Comment: do you want DagB to start anyway and continue with his tasks only if DagA succeeded? Or do you want to Start DagB only if DagA succeeded? the difference is that in option B you can trigger DagB from DagA in case of success

Comment: I want to start DagB only if DagA succecded in same day. DagA start at 10 AM and finished at 10:05 AM and DagB also start at 10 AM and reach to the step where need to get the state of DagA exuection on same day. If DagA is not started on same day then DagB should fail.

Answer (score 0):

In DagB you can create a BranchPythonOperator that finds the last run of DagA and decide if to continue with next task or raise exception.

in the example below, I am checking if DagA was running in the same day (midnight to now) and with state=success. if I have results I am returning the name of the next task to run, else I raise exception and DagB fails.

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import DagRun, TaskInstance
from airflow.operators.python import  BranchPythonOperator, PythonOperator
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
from airflow.utils import timezone
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

with DAG(
        dag_id="DagB",
        start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
        schedule_interval=None,
        render_template_as_native_obj=True,
        tags=["DagB"],
) as dag:
    def check_success_dag_a(**context):
        ti: TaskInstance = context['ti']
        dag_run: DagRun = context['dag_run']
        date: datetime = ti.execution_date
        ts = timezone.make_aware(datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day, 0, 0, 0))
        dag_a = dag_run.find(
            dag_id='DagA',
            state='success',
            execution_start_date=ts,
            execution_end_date=ti.execution_date)
        if dag_a:
            return "taskB"
        raise AirflowException("DagA failed")


    check_success = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id="check_success_dag_a",
        python_callable=check_success_dag_a,
    )


    def run():
        print('DagB')

    run_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="taskB",
        dag=dag,
        python_callable=run,
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS
    )

    (check_success >> [run_task])
```

Comment: If date is not same in that case.. It will return none and will throw the error. Need to handle None as well.

Comment: I think your code will not work as we have to compare DagA and DagB day

Comment: @user13748181 in the filter I am asking only for DagA that ran in the day DagB is running. should be one or none. hope I understand you well. also the idea is the "find" function that give you the way to find prev runs of different Dags and make decisions

Comment: but code is throwing error even DagA is in Success state.

Comment: What is the error?  I raise error to fail the dag if condition  not match. Maybe you need to change the condition.